# Javascript regex and parseInt

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript regex to match numbers in a string, which I to multiply and replace.

```
'foo1 bar2.7'.replace(/(\d+\.?\d*)/g, parseInt('$1', 10) * 2);
```

I want it to return `'foo2 bar5.4'` but it returns `'fooNaN barNaN'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`parseInt('$1', 10) * 2` is executed first and its **result** is passed to `replace`. You want to use a callback function:

```
'foo1 bar2.7'.replace(/(\d+\.?\d*)/g, function(match, number) {
    return +number * 2;
});
```

Furthermore, `parseInt` will round down any floating point value, so the result would be `"foo2 bar4"`. Instead you can use the *unary plus operator* to convert any numerical string into a number.

Comment: Huh..'+number'?Why do you use '+number',please explain it,thank you very much.

Comment: It should be explained by the last sentence: *"Instead you can use the unary plus operator to convert any numerical string into a number."*

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the result of `parseInt('$1', 10) * 2` to the `replace` function, rather than the statement itself.

Instead, you can **pass** a function to `replace` like so:

```
'foo1 bar2.7'.replace(/(\d+\.?\d*)/g, function (str) {
    return parseInt(str, 10) * 2;
});
```

For more info, read the [MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) on passing functions as a parameter to `String.replace`

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have more than one grouping, you can do something like:

```
"p-622-5350".replace(/p-(\d+)-(\d+)/, function (match, g1, g2) { 
    return "p-" + (+g1 * 10) + "-" + (+g2 *10); 
});
```

(note the extra parameters in the function)